# Is it possible to remove spaces from existing images?

Tags: images

I have changed my WordPress blog theme but now in older posts images are not working. I have used images names with space `:/` and it is not working now in this theme. I can see the name like `something%20icon.png`. Can I fix it somehow? Not manually all image.

Update: I have find out that problem is that old images that are not working are in root/images (new one are in wp-content\upload...). If I tried url of some image, website.com/images/image.jpg it will open main website not an image. There are images in directory.

Comment: What do you mean with _not working?_ Do you get a 404 for these images? That shouldn't be related to the theme at all.

Comment: I see there is a plugin that converts spaces to dashes for files in media library: [Clean Image Filenames](https://wordpress.org/plugins/clean-image-filenames/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test flowing code

```
$img_space = 'something icon.png';
$img_without_space = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $im);
echo $image;
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem? The original image locations stay the same.

Comment: ah sry, I have found that problem is not in that space... Some of images are in direcotry images which is in root and new images are in wp-content\uploads\...  But when I tried to open some image with www.website.com\images\example.png, it still open main page, www.website.com... not image. But images are on the server... where should be problem, just some permission...?